# How to display fps of streaming video in gsteramer?

Tags: gstreamer, raspberry-pi4

I'm using ov5647 MIPI sensor with Raspberry Pi 4 model B, to stream video I'm using gstreamer with v4l2 to stream

command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

what modification do I need to do with above command, to display fps?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [fpsdisplaysink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/debugutilsbad/fpsdisplaysink.html?gi-language=c) element as follows::

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=xvimagesink text-overlay=false sync=false -v 2>&1`

- `-v 2>&1` - redirects output to stdout
- `text-overlay=true` - renders the FPS information into the video stream.